# Imprimir Matriz (C)

Tags: c, array

Estou tentando imprimir uma matriz com os meses, mas não estou conseguindo.
É um teste para outro código do qual estou fazendo.
O objetivo é ficar:

```
Janeiro Fevereiro
Março Abril
Maio Junho
Julho Agosto
Setembro Outubro
Novembro Dezembro
```

O que eu fiz foi isto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char mes[12][15] = 
    {
      "Janeiro", "Fevereiro",
      "Março", "Abril",
      "Maio", "Junho",
      "Julho", "Agosto",
      "Setembro", "Outubro",
      "Novembro", "Dezembro"
    };
    
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int col = 2;
    
    int lin = 12; // meses
  while(x < 12)
  {
    for (j; lin > j; lin--)  //6 meses em cada coluna
    {
        for (i; col > i; col--) 
        {
            printf("%s", mes[i]); //imprime mes impar
          
        }
        
        printf("%s\n", mes[j]); //imprime mes par e pula de linha
      
    }
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mas você está utilizando `i` e `j` como índices de seu array mas não está variando nenhum deles. Talvez seja mais fácil fazer: `for (i=0;i<12; i++) { printf("%s", mes[i]); if (i%2 == 0) printf("\t"); else printf("\n");}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está complicando o algoritmo à toa.

Basta fazer um `for` de 0 a 11 (pois os índices de um array começam em zero).

Se o índice for par, quer dizer que ele é o primeiro da linha, então você imprime um espaço depois. Se for ímpar, quer dizer que ele é o segundo da linha, então você imprime a quebra de linha depois. Assim:

```
char mes[12][15] = {
  "Janeiro", "Fevereiro",
  "Março", "Abril",
  "Maio", "Junho",
  "Julho", "Agosto",
  "Setembro", "Outubro",
  "Novembro", "Dezembro"
};

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    printf("%s", mes[i]);
    if (i % 2 == 0) printf(" ");
    else printf("\n");
}
```

O operador `%` retorna o resto da divisão, assim eu sei se o número é par ou ímpar. A saída é:

```
Janeiro Fevereiro
Março Abril
Maio Junho
Julho Agosto
Setembro Outubro
Novembro Dezembro
```